# How do I make a form submit only after another form gets posted successfully using only 1 submit button?

Tags: php, forms

I have 2 forms on my web page. I want to give the illusion that they are being submitted simultaneously. I need one form to process and if it fails, don't process the 2nd form. The first form is payment information. The 2nd form is an "ask question" form. How do I do this? I am using PHP for server side code. [Her is a screenshot of my 2 forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQFYj.jpg) for anyone wondering. Note: I removed the "Pay" button used to submit the Braintree form because I want there to only be one submit button - the plugin's "Post Question" button.

1. How do I begin the overall submission process for both forms using only 1 button?
2. How do I restrict the 2nd form to be posted only after the first goes through successfully?

Comment: You can simply use JS for this.

Comment: @jlam55555 understood, but I'm new to web dev and I'm not sure how to even begin writing JS code for this. I'm trying to learn it from tutorials but the journey is arduous. So I thought I'd ask on here. Could you provide maybe like a general example of what "handlers" to use?

Comment: Do you get all the information to both forms in just one time?

Comment: @IagoMelanias yes, both forms are present on the page simultaneously. The user will fill out all the fields from the top of the page to the bottom, not knowing that they are 2 forms. I want them to use 1 submit button to further maintain this illusion.

Comment: So why use 2 forms? You can simply use one form, do the back-end logic to check if the first form didn't fail and process the second form logic in just one request. Do this using 2 forms would be more complicated.

Comment: @DarthVoid I'm typing up an example to show you the JS part... sorry it's taking so long...

Comment: @IagoMelanias it's because one of the forms is a Braintree payment entry form. I emailed their support and they wrote back saying: *While you definitely do need a form element in order to create your integration, something you might consider is specifying a form ID for your Braintree payment form, and keep that independent from your other form. This will allow you to utilize all of the callbacks and other events necessary to the functioning of the Drop-in UI.*. For clarity, the Drop-in UI is their simply credit card entry form that I am working with.

Comment: Also, I'm worried about PCI compliance. I also had the idea of keeping it all in 1 form, but then I wondered how this would affect me legally. Would the payment info fields (CC #, Exp date, CVV) that the user types in pass through my server in a way that would negatively affect PCI compliance? Braintree advised that using their API in the manner instructed would give me the greatest chance of staying compliant, so that's another reason why I wanted to follow what they are saying and use 2 forms. If you still advise against this or have other ideas, then by all means let me know.

Comment: I'm still new to web development, so I'm not going to pretend that the first few conclusions I arrive it will necessarily be the ones I stick with. I'm open to all criticism :)

Comment: @DarthVoid That's a great attitude for developing!

Comment: @DarthVoid Sorry to carry on this conversation and bug you, but if the answer works, accept it please. If it doesn't tell me why not?

Comment: @jlam55555 no worries. I'm trying to figure out how to relate it to my exact code. So far I tested both form's individual submissions using their own submit buttons. Now I need to use your code and change/add some lines to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[This](http://jsfiddle.net/n4y1r5gy/) JSFiddle should work.</strike>

<strike>It simply has a simple conditional factor in the first form (which you can modify to check for correct payment info), and the second form has the submit button. If the first form's information is incorrect, it will not send by using a `return false;`. If it does go through, then it first sends the first form with `form.submit();` and then goes through with the second form.</strike>

**Edit**: The above answer just sends both forms - it does not check that the first one *goes through*, but it insteads does some basic JS validation.

So supposing that you had the two forms (because your imgur link was broken and I can't tell what they really look like):

```
<form action="braintree.php">
    <!-- Payment options -->
</form>
<form action="questions.php">
    <!-- The questions you want -->
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And supposing that you have the `braintree.php` file: (you are using PHP, right?)

```
<?php
     // send data to braintree
     if(/* payment goes through */) {
         echo "0";    // echo error code 0 (no error) for JS
     } else {
         echo "1";    // echo error code 1 (error) for JS
                      // if you can get an error back from braintree, 
                      // then you can add it here -- it will be sent 
                      // back to JS and you can show it to the user
     }
?>
```

And supposing that you have JQuery (JS) like so:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    // manually send first form with AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: "braintree.php",
        method: "post",
        asynch: false,    // so that the second form waits for this request to finish
        data: {
            // put in all the data to send in the braintree file here
            fname: $("#fname").val();
            lname: $("#lname").val();
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        // data will be the response from "braintree.php"
        if(data == "0") {
            return true;
        } else {
            // if you have a more specific error, you can alert() it here
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This code is untested, so tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: In the JSFiddle example, the checkbox example is based on a field being marked. So you want me to relate this to my 1st form by checking if the fields are filled in (similar to the checkbox). But I don't think this is exactly what I'm looking for (it's very close though!). I want the 1st form to be completely submitted before attempting to submit the second one. This is because I want to be sure that the entire payment submission process goes through successfully. Am I correct in assuming that's how most payment + web services work?

Comment: For example, if I want to buy something on Amazon, the payment would have to go through first before Amazon starts writing the order details to their order history table for my account. Also, the payment would have to go through before notifying the seller that they must ship to me.

Comment: @DarthVoid that's when you use AJAX and wait for a response. I guess I could help explain that too.

Comment: It looks like I'll need to stray away from the Drop-in UI given by Braintree in order to fully test this. I started with it because it was their way of getting started quickly, but I think it's not really working because I haven't set up my own custom form yet. I'll do so then test this again.